# Javascript - How to validate two phone numbers to be different

Tags: javascript, validation

I have two fields for phone number - 1. Phone number 2. Alternate phone number.

So the users should enter different phone number in "Alternate phone number" field. If they enter the same number as in the 1st field "Phone number" it should throw alert message that "Alternate phone number" should be different.

I want javascript code that validates the above.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stackoverflow. Second, what have you tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: Is comparing them as strings not enough?

Answer (score 2):

This is just comparing two string, like this:

```
var p1 = document.getElementById('yourInputPhone1ID');
var p2 = document.getElementById('yourInputPhone2ID');
// Comparison
if(p1.value != ''){
    if(p1.value == p2.value){
      alert('Alternate phone number should be different');
    }
 }
 else{
   alert('missing phone number 1');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For first Phone number validation you can use your js function in on submit:

```
function validatePhone(txtPhone) {
    var a = document.getElementById(txtPhone).value;
    var filter = /^[0-9-+]+$/;
    if (filter.test(a)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}​
```

To validate your second phone number differently, you could create one more JS function with above code and update the RegEx in filter as per your needs.